# Reduce duplication with similar if condition in ruby

Tags: ruby

When implementing a recursive function like a maze problem. I will try to move to 4 direction, each step seems quite similar.

```
if current_y+1<@y_length and @map[current_y+1][current_x].undected?
    path.push current_point
    next_point=  @map[current_y+1][current_x]       
    flag=DFS(next_point,target_point,path)
    if flag=='found'
        return flag
    end
end
if current_y-1>=0 and @map[current_y-1][current_x].undected?
    path.push current_point
    next_point= @map[current_y-1][current_x]
    flag=DFS(next_point,target_point,path)
    if flag=='found'
        return flag
    end
end
if current_x+1<@x_length and @map[current_y][current_x+1].undected?
    path.push current_point
    next_point=@map[current_y][current_x+1]
    flag=DFS(next_point,target_point,path)
    if flag=='found'
        return flag
    end
end
if current_x-1>=0 and @map[current_y][current_x-1].undected?
    path.push current_point
    next_point=@map[current_y][current_x-1]
    flag=DFS(next_point,target_point,path)
    if flag=='found'
        return flag
    end
end
```

how to make it as short as possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And a simple list with an each statement would not work?

```
    directions = [
    [current_y+1<@y_length,current_y+1,current_x],
    [current_y-1>=0, current_y-1, current_x],
    [current_x+1<@x_length,current_y, current_x+1],
    [current_x-1>=0,current_x-1]
]

directions.each do |check_condition, y, x|

  next if @map[y][x].undected?
  next if check_condition

  path.push(current_point)
  next_point=@map[y][x]
  flag=DFS(next_point,target_point,path)

  return flag if flag=='found'

end
```

Comment: thanks,  now I have done it by putting method object in array and go through it, quite similar like yours. I like your solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
path.push current_point
if current_y+1<@y_length && @map[current_y+1][current_x].undected?
  next_point=  @map[current_y+1][current_x]
elsif current_y-1>=0 and @map[current_y-1][current_x].undected?
  next_point= @map[current_y-1][current_x]
elsif current_x+1<@x_length and @map[current_y][current_x+1].undected?
  next_point=@map[current_y][current_x+1]
elsif current_x-1>=0 and @map[current_y][current_x-1].undected?
  next_point=@map[current_y][current_x-1]
end
flag=DFS(next_point,target_point,path)
if flag=='found'
  return flag
end
```

Comment: Sorry, I forget to  stress it is a recursive function, which means every if branch have to be go through.